# Does this C code result in Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, operator-precedence, sequence-points

I know that:

```
int b = 1, c = 2, d = 3, e = 4;
printf("%d %d %d", ++b, b, b++);
```

results in undefined behavior. Since

> Modifying any object more than once between two sequence points is UB.
> [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

But I don't know if:

```
int b = 1, c = 2, d = 3, e = 4;
printf("%d", b++ + ++c - --d - e--);
```

is also UB?

What I think is that increment/decrement operators will evalute first because of the precedence, between them right to left since the  associativity . Then arithmetic operators will be evaluated left to right.

Which will just be

> (b) + (c + 1) - (d - 1) - (e)

> that is, 1 + (2 + 1) - (3 - 1) - (4)

> = (2 - 4)

> = -2

Is it right?

Comment: It results in a compilation error. If you fix the quotes and put it in a function then it's fine because each variable is only accessed in one place.

Comment: It's not really a precedence issue, but rather an evaluation issue.

Comment: The precedence rules do not matter. The value of `b++ + ++c - --d - e--` is the "sum" of values `b++`, `++c`, `--d`, and `e--`. The value of `b++` is the value of `b` at the last sequence point, the value of `++c` is `1` more than the value of `c` at the last sequence point, .... (the side effect of updates to variables within sequence points does not change these values)

Comment: Why would you think the second code could be UB?

Comment: You can try it and modern compilers will give a warning. For GCC it is with `-Wsequence-point` and for clang with `-Wunsequenced` (both are enabled by `-Wall`, which you should be used anyway).

Comment: I tried using `-Wall`,  but the second code didn't give any warning.

Comment: See [What is the difference between operator precedence and order of evaluation?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278172).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gigantic difference between the expressions

```
b++ + ++c - --d - e--
```

(which is fine), and

```
x++ + ++x - --x - x--
```

(which is rampantly undefined).

It's not using `++` or `--` that makes an expression undefined.  It's not even using `++` or `--` twice in the same expression.  No, the problem is when you use `++` or `--` to modify a variable inside an expression, *and* you also try to use the value of that same variable elsewhere in the same expression, and without an intervening sequence point.

Consider the simpler expression

```
++z + z;
```

Now, obviously the subexpression `++z` will increment `z`.  So the question is, does the `+ z` part use the old or the new value of z?  And the answer is that there is no answer, which is why this expression is undefined.

Remember, expressions like `++z` do *not* just mean, "take `z`'s value and add 1".  They mean, "take `z`'s value and add 1, and store the result back into `z`".  These expressions have *side effects*.  And the side effects are at the root of the undefinedness issue.

Answer (score 7):

> But I don't know if: ... is also UB?

It is not, but your reasoning about why is fuzzy.

> What I think is that increment/decrement operators will evaluate first because of the precedence, between them right to left since the associativity . Then arithmetic operators will be evaluated left to right.

Precedence determines how the result is calculated. It doesn't say anything about the ordering of the side-effects.

There is no equivalent of precedence telling you when the side effects (the stored value of `b` has been incremented, the stored value of `e` has been decremented) are observable *during the statement*. All you know is that the variables have taken their new values before the *next* statement (ie, by the `;`).

So, the reason this is well-defined is that it *does not depend on those side-effects*.

---

I deliberately hand-waved the language to avoid getting bogged down, but I should probably clarify:

- "*during the statement*" really means "**before the next sequence point**"
- "before the *next* statement (... `;`)" really means "**at the next sequence point**"

See [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order):

> 1. There is a sequence point after the evaluation of all function arguments and of the function designator, and before the actual function call.

So *really* the side-effects are committed before the call to `printf`, so earlier than the `;` at the end of the statement.

Comment: I believe the side-effects will have taken place before the function (`printf`) is called. That's not relevant here but a called function may have a way of accessing variables modified during the statement.

Comment: Yeah, I elaborated on that - I'd tried to avoid including the sequence point rules to just focus on the confusion between operator precedence and order of evaluation.

Comment: I really like the answer. The order of precedence vs evaluation is a great cause of confusion and you explain it well. That's why I decided to be pedantic about your answer rather than offer my own.